# Why is the CD/DVD unmounted each time it is accessed?

Tags: macos, music.app

I recently connected my LG external CD drive to my M1 Mac Mini running 12.1, and I have an odd problem: whenever a CD or DVD is accessed (tested mostly with CDs), the disk is immediately unmounted.

Initially I suspected the problem was VLC, which would throw a "can't access file" error, after playing a second or two of the audio on the CD. However, in using the Music app the fault is the same. In fact, if I select the CD in Finder, it will briefly show the audio files, before the window disappears as the disk is unmounted, so it doesn't appear to be an Application-specific issue, but rather an OS one?

I would say the problem manifests itself 90% of the time when i'm trying to read a CD, and it isn't consistent with which disc it is, ie. sometimes disc A will be read first time without any issue, but subsequent times I can't get it to read. The drive has been good previously, and is pretty new so I don't suspect it to be a hardware fault. I did update to Monterey recently, but it has been a while since I last used the CD drive, so I can't comment whether it was working in the previous OSX version.

I'm not really sure what the next troubleshooting steps would be, so any suggestions are welcome, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a replacement good quality cable?

Comment: Yes, I tried a different USB cable (and a USB2 rather than USB3, also), and the results were the same, thanks.